# Adobe Analytics DTM - Prevent initial server call on specific pages/subdomains?

Tags: javascript, adobe, analytics, adobe-analytics

I'm using Adobe DTM. What I'm trying to figure out is the best way to prevent the initial page load server call from going out on specific pages. The reason is, many parts of our website are 3rd party integrations separated by subdomains. Some of these 3rd party sites are Single Page Applications (SPA). Since most of our site is not a SPA, I need to figure out how to stop the initial server call when I hit one of these subdomains? The vendor is updating the s.pageName variable mapping on their end so I need to prevent the initial call from firing or I'll get two calls initially. I have a data element and event-based rule set-up to detect a change in the page name. I just need to stop it the first time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DTM, to prevent that default beacon on page load, you need to put a "return false" statement for those urls somewhere in your Adobe tool code. http://www.digitaldatatactics.com/examples/DCRsuppress.html has an example.

Comment: I was actually able to use a global page load rule for Analytics and put the code "s.abort=true;" in the Abobe Analytics tools script section with conditional statement around it.

Comment: @MichaelJohns keep in mind that `s.abort` does not suppress the `s.t` call itself from getting triggered. `s.t` will still trigger, so if you have a `s.doPlugins` defined, it will also eval, which may impact tracking (e.g. cookie based tracking).

Comment: @Crayon Violent - thanks for the info but this is in the context of DTM so no s.doPlugins